# Minimal latex installation for headless server

Tags: server, latex, headless

I have a (headless) server running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
I would like to install latex, mainly to embed latex fonts in plots
with Python/matplotlib.

Is there a minimimal latex installation option which is suggested for headless servers, e.g. free from all graphical tools? The standard installation procedure:

```
apt-get install texlive-full
```

requires about 6GB on the machine, I was wondering whether anything lighter is around.

Cheers,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

There are several `Tex Live` packages available on `Ubuntu`'s repository<sup>[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245982/differences-between-texlive-packages-in-linux#answer-504566)</sup>. You can install `texlive`<sup>[2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/texlive)</sup> meta package.

To install `texlive` package run

```
sudo apt install texlive
```

This install takes close to `900MB`s (including dependencies) in disk space.

---

<sup>1. Comparison of different `Tex Live` packages and their size: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245982/differences-between-texlive-packages-in-linux#answer-504566.</sup>
<sup>2. About `texlive` package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/texlive.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you do not need complicated formulas, just the font and simple texts: Use a font that is similar to Computer Modern. For example, Latin Modern (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Modern): its OpenType format should be compatible with matplotlib, according to https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/fonts.html. Other possibility is to use the [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) fonts as OpenType, currently they can be downloaded, for example, from https://a3nm.net/mathjax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/ (which is an unofficial site).

In this case you do not have to have the whole LaTeX system, just a set of fonts. You will surely save most of the space.